# #Sequelize findAll events and forEach event getUser

Tags: javascript, promise, sequelize.js, findall

I got some problems with Sequelize and promise (mainly with promise).
Example :
I want all my Events and the master of this events. I've done something like that :

```
 models.events.findAll().then(function(event) {
     events.forEach(function(event){
         events.dataValues.master = event.getUsers({
               where: ['UserRelationEvent.relation = "master"'],
               joinTableAttributes: []
         }).then(function(user){
               return user[0].dataValues;
         });
     });
     return next(events);
 }).catch(function(err) {next(err)});
```

But there I got an Sequelize Object.. I checked my content of `user[0].dataValues` It's exactly what I want.. so I think I miss something and misunderstood something with promises :/
I try many things but mainly my question is : how can I retrieve my string from my console.log

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`event.getUsers` returns a promise - so you are assigning `events.dataValues.master` (which is the array, not the particular event btw) the promise, not the value.

Also, you are returning `next`, before `getUsers` is done, because they happen async

Something like this should work

```
models.events.findAll().then(function(events) {
     sequelize.Promise.each(events, function(event){
         return event.getUsers({
               through: {
                    where: { relation: 'master' }
               },
               joinTableAttributes: []
         }).then(function(user){
                event.dataValues.master = user[0];
         });
     }).then(function (events) {
        return next(events);
     });
}).catch(function(err) {next(err);});
```

When you return a promise to the callback in promise.each, the `then` (which calls `next`) is not invoked, before all the returned promises are done (i.e. before all `getUsers` calls are done.
I've also changed the where clause to use an object instead of string :)

But wait! We can do better!

```
models.events.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: User,
            through: {
                where: {
                    relation: 'master'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}).then(function(events) {
    return next(events);
}).catch(function(err) {next(err);});
```

This left joins the users table where the relation is master. You may want to do a map in the `then`, because users will be placed under `.users`, not `.master`